porting C++ CLR .NET framework Winform to .NET 8
we have a tool that was written in C++ CLR where its forms where also written as a Winform in C++ CLR, we plan to upgrade it to .NET 8 but it seems there is a pretty huge shift between .net framework and .NET 8 and/or future versions like 9.So I am assuming that the way to do this will be pretty tedious. so here are my questions

in the unified .NET version (5 or higher), I assume the only way to create winforms is thru C# and there is no longer support for C++ CLR winforms?

I read from somewhere (or even from the compile logs) that I need to build my C++ CLR to DLL to make it work and create a C# project that uses that DLL, I assume the winforms cannot be used now right?

does that mean that I need to recareate the forms, dialogs and controls form my C++ CLR projects in C# and they cannot be reused?


I have tried changing the exe (Application) project from .Net framework v4.8 to .NET 7 and i got bunch of errors, and also a suggestion from logs that says build it as a DLL,
So I guess there is no other way but to redo it,
Is there any other way or is it the only way and I cant use my forms, dialogs and user control anymore?

Support for creating Winforms apps in C++/CLI was removed 12 years ago.  It didn't get better.

Can't see why it wouldn't work direct from C++/CLI, even if it's unsupported, you just need to add the relevant Nuget. You might have difficulty with the designers etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli Have been there for a few years now. If you read something different from elsewhere, verify if enough evidence is presented.
